# Move to last instance of a given character in the line in vim?

Tags: vim

Is there a quick way to move to the last instance of a given character in the current line? For example, go to the last close paren in the line. I don't want to type `f)` fifteen times to go there, and using / isn't restricted to the current line (I'm writing in Scheme).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Just do:

```
$F)
```

- `$` to jump to the end of the line,
- `F)` to jump to the first `)` *backward*.

Comment: D'oh! Well, now I feel dumb. I'll accept your answer in a few minutes, unless someone can come up with something that involves even less finger movement.

Comment: By the way, `%` jumps to the closing `)`.